# Pinging with microsoft visio

Tags: monitoring, communication, ping, visio

I need to use visio in order to monitor communication to certain routers and servers.
I saw som information on that but i didn't understand what to do.
Do any of know how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This kind of sucks - I wish I could do something about that...

Answer (score 0):

try use this add-in. [System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2 add-in for Visio 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26228)

i just see video about it, but don't use.

[image]